# Ionic icons are not showing in some pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I create a custom component called bookmark where I'm just showing my bookmark icon.

**bookmark.html**

```
<button ion-fab class="bookmark-button">
  <ion-icon *ngIf="!flag; else elseBlocked" ios="ios-bookmark" md="md-bookmark" [ngStyle]="{'color': '#9F9F9F'}" class="bookmark-icon"></ion-icon>
  <ng-template #elseBlocked><ion-icon ios="ios-bookmark" md="md-bookmark" class="bookmark-icon" [ngStyle]="{'color': '#FF6260'}"></ion-icon></ng-template> 
</button>
```

**bookmark.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BookmarkComponent } from './bookmark';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      BookmarkComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    BookmarkComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(BookmarkComponent),
  ],
})
export class BookmarkComponentModule {}
```

Now when I'm importing this component module in ionic pages sometimes it doesn't show the bookmark icon. Like in Homepage it's working just fine but when I'm importing in some other module like Resultpage then it doesn't work at all.

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPageModule } from "ionic-angular";
import { HomePage } from "./home";
import { BookmarkComponentModule } from "../../components/bookmark/bookmark.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    BookmarkComponentModule,
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

**result.module.ts**

```
import { BookmarkComponentModule } from './../../components/bookmark/bookmark.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ResultPage } from './result';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ResultPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ResultPage),
    BookmarkComponentModule
  ],
})
export class ResultPageModule {}
```

I don't know where I go wrong. Any suggestions...

Comment: any error on console? posr your component where you use

Comment: No, It doesn't throw any error. I've checked in inspect element and the icon is there but doesn't show but if I doesn't import the bookmark component in Resultpage then the icons works just fine.

Comment: that cannot happen, produce a stackblitz

Comment: why are you using `IonicModule.forRoot(BookmarkComponent),` ?

Comment: I'm using this so that I can use ionic icons in my component

Comment: Share ts file of your bookmark component plz

Comment: I've tried every possible options but the error won't resolve

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your quick responses but I seemed to resolve this issue by changing the import statement on the component page.

**bookmark.module.ts**

*before*

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(BookmarkComponent),
    BookmarkComponentModule
],
```

*after*

```
imports: [
    IonicModule,
    BookmarkComponentModule
],
```

When I change my import statement on every component I've been using the problem seems to be gone.